# Load childViewController to scrollview parent with a button

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, parent-child, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I'm using the PageViewController (https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/pageviewcontroller) to create a Magazine App similar to Wired.

I've used this code on CustomPagerViewController to load the childview's:

```
- (IBAction)btn_index:(id)sender {

NSInteger currentPage = 3;
CGPoint offset = CGPointMake(currentPage * self.scrollView.frame.size.width, 0);
[self.scrollView setContentOffset:offset animated:YES];}
```

But I need several buttons on the indexviewcontroller to load the correct views and when I use the same code,

> Property 'scrollView' not found on object of type
>   'Pag4_5ViewController *'

I've searched and tried several methods but all in vain.

Does anyone have any idea on how to solve this problem?

Comment: is "scrollView" a outlet of Scrollview? have you synthesized it?

Comment: @ Abhijit Chaudhari yes, the scrollView is "@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;" and I've synthesized it on PagerViewController. Actually I've used the PagerViewController.h and .m from the link.

Comment: where are you defining the btn_index action? and what is "Pag4_5ViewController".

Comment: @AbhijitChaudhari the btn_index is defined in the Pag4_5ViewController  which is the index page of my Magazine. I need several buttons to "load" the correct magazine page's without losing the scroll

Comment: You used `PagerViewController.h` and `PagerViewController.m` from [PageViewController](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/pageviewcontroller) , but what is `Pag4_5ViewController`? It is subclass of `PagerViewController`? Or you rewrites it? Property `scroll` declared in `Pag4_5ViewController.h` file? Your error message means what property `scroll` not declared in `Pag4_5ViewController` class and superclass in `@interface` section, or declared in superclass as `private`.

Comment: @RuslanSoldatenko the Pag4_5ViewController is the ViewController that I've created for my index page (the 3d load by the scroll).

Comment: As should from error message `Pag4_5ViewController` is  a class, not an object. As should from your words "the `Pag4_5ViewController` is the `ViewController`", that is `Pag4_5ViewController` is subclass of  `UIViewController`, it correct?

Comment: Yes @RuslanSoldatenko

Comment: [UIViewController](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) as default have not property `scroll`. Your `Pag4_5ViewController` have property `scroll` declared in `Pag4_5ViewController.h` file in `@interface` section?

Comment: @RuslanSoldatenko no because the scroll is declared in the parent class

Comment: If `scroll` declared in parent class (i.e. in superclass) - what is this class? Some time ago you say what `Pag4_5ViewController` is subclass of `UIViewController` (i.e. `UIViewController` is parent for `Pag4_5ViewController`). And as I wrote above - `UIViewController` as default have not property `scroll`. May be you need change superclass of `Pag4_5ViewController` from `UIViewController` to `PagerViewController`?

Comment: @RuslanSoldatenko the PagerViewController is parent of CustomPagerViewController and load's the pages. However the pages are all different (some have webviews, others slideshow's/animations), I've created different classes for each one of them in order to customize them. The Pag4_5ViewController is the class where is my magazine's index.

Comment: In this case you need to add to `Pag4_5ViewController` class property `scroll`. And when you create instance of `Pag4_5ViewController` class you must set property `scroll` by value of  `scroll` property of  `CustomPagerViewController` class instance.

Comment: @RuslanSoldatenko And how do I do that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42647/discussion-between-ruslan-soldatenko-and-svennpt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After talks in chat solution has been found and it is necessary to fix. The problem was that the `self` in this context (Pag4_5ViewController.m file) pointer to an instance of Pag4_5ViewController, and needed access to the methods of class `CustomPagerViewController` instance. After getting acquainted with the project found a solution. And one of the embodiments given below:

Add in Pag4_5ViewController class (and to other classes) line:

```
#import "CustomPagerViewController.h"
```

and change code to something like this:

```
- (IBAction)btn_index:(id)sender
{
  CustomPagerViewController *parent = (CustomPagerViewController *)[self parentViewController];
  //page number where the transition will be accomplished
  NSInteger currentPage = 3;// 3 in Pag4_5ViewController.m file do nothing, because it is an index of the same page. But it be correct work for other pages.
  CGPoint offset = CGPointMake(currentPage * parent.scrollView.frame.size.width, 0);
  [parent.scrollView setContentOffset:offset animated:YES];
}
```

Note: This is just one of the possible variants of the code that will work. But there may be others.