# CATransition scroll animation

Tags: ios, animation, transition, catransition

I'm using CATransition animation to segue between my views with swype gesture. Is there any way to make this animation looks like scroll/paging between my views?

Here's my code:

```
-(void)perform {

    UIViewController *sourceViewController = (UIViewController*)[self sourceViewController];
    UIViewController *destinationController = (UIViewController*)[self destinationViewController];                    

    CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.2;
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush; //kCATransitionMoveIn; //, kCATransitionPush, kCATransitionReveal, kCATransitionFade
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight; //kCATransitionFromLeft, kCATransitionFromRight, kCATransitionFromTop, kCATransitionFromBottom

    [sourceViewController.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];

    [sourceViewController.navigationController pushViewController:destinationController animated:NO];

}
```

Comment: May be you need something like [UIPageViewController](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-tutorial-intro/). Or [UIScrollView with paging](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ScrollViewPagingMode/ScrollViewPagingMode.html). If not, describe in detail how should look like animation.

Comment: @RuslanSoldatenko it's exactly that animation that I'm looking for. The problem is that I already have a complete app without PageViewController or ScrollView. I've tried use those controllers but I had a problem that I couldn't solve, if you would like to help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20328891/load-childviewcontroller-to-scrollview-parent-with-a-button